Job failed using spark-submit with parameters when job runs in Azure databricks.. INIT_SCRIPT_FAILURE (CLIENT_ERROR)
I created a simple netcore3.1 project and ran locally successfully. I wanted to test the Microsoft netcore3.1 application into azure databricks cluster to run job. I followed the instruction as per Microsoft documentation, but job failed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/spark/tutorials/databricks-deployment
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
.Builder()
.AppName("HelloWorldSparkApp")
.GetOrCreate();

 // Create a DataFrame with a single row and single column  
 DataFrame df = spark.Sql("SELECT 'Hello, World!' AS message");

 // Show the DataFrame  
 df.Show();

 // Stop the Spark session  
 spark.Stop();

Cluster configuration

single node
Databricks runtime version : runtime 10.4(Scala 2.12,spark 3.2.1)
Node type: standard_d4ds_v5
Advanced Options: Init Script (WorkSpace and ABFSS options. No DBFS option and also shows warning message)



copied db-init.sh to workspace->shared folder because there is no DBFS option.
Job configuration

Task name: testjob
Type : Spark-Submit
Cluster : created earlier
parameters :
["--class","org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner",
"/dbfs/spark-dotnet/microsoft-spark-3-2_2.12-2.1.1.jar",
"/dbfs/spark-dotnet/HelloSparkCore31.zip","HelloSparkCore31"]

Publish application:

Using VS2019 publish, self -contained option and runtime win-x64
create a zip file

Databricks dbfs/spark-dotnet folder content as per ms documentation
-db-init.sh
-install-worker.sh
-microsoft-spark-3-2_2.12-2.1.1.jar
-Microsoft.Spark.Worker.netcoreapp3.1.linux-x64-2.1.1.tar.gz
-HelloSparkCore31.zip
Job creation is okey but got exception when job starts.
Exception as per job output
Cluster '0901-204609-m9yiukve' was terminated. Reason: INIT_SCRIPT_FAILURE (CLIENT_ERROR). Parameters: instance_id:93d671e9f0884221b689a09b125d2655, databricks_error_message:Cluster scoped init script /Shared/db-init.sh failed: Script exit status is non-zero.

I am in learning stage about databricks. I searched google a lot but could not resolve.
Any kind of help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

First make sure you altered the db-init.sh appropriately, whatever the folders need to be created and using supported versions.
That is install-worker.sh should be in /dbfs/spark-dotnet as per the script but the using scripts in dbfs location is depreciated
so please use different spark-dotnet root folder.
Also use latest DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE which is Release .NET for Apache Spark v2.1.1 · dotnet/spark · GitHub
So, alter your DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE in script.
DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE=https://github.com/dotnet/spark/releases/download/v2.1.1/Microsoft.Spark.Worker.netcoreapp3.1.linux-x64-2.1.1.tar.gz

Also check the logs in dbfs:/cluster-logs/ for more about executing of this scripts.

Thank you @JayashankarGS for your detailed info. I followed netcore3.1 deployment steps  just for testing whether it works or not. I copied .tar.gz file to dbfs:/FileStore/MSWorker folder. I did not tough in install-worker file. My Init script is as follows.

DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE= /dbfs/FileStore/MSWorker
DBFS_INSTALLATION_ROOT=/dbfs/spark-dotnet
DOTNET_SPARK_WORKER_INSTALLATION_PATH=/usr/local/bin
set +e
/bin/bash $DBFS_INSTALLATION_ROOT/install-worker.sh azure $DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE $DOTNET_SPARK_WORKER_INSTALLATION_PATH

My plan is to use .Net8.0. So, I used the same code for .Net 8.0. Now I have a few questions.  1. Should I publish the code as self-contained or not and runtime winx-64 or linux-x64? 2. Can I use the "Microsoft.Spark.Worker.netcore3.1.linux-64-2.1.1.tar.gz" for .Net8.0 application. If not where can I get .Net8.0 .tar.gz file. The links does not show any .tar.gz file for either .Net6.0 or 8.0.

DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE=https://github.com/dotnet/spark/releases/download/v2.1.1/Microsoft.Spark.Worker.netcoreapp3.1.linux-x64-2.1.1.tar.gz  try this also keep you script in workspace not in dbfs.

Thanks. I also tried they way you mentioned but failed. However, I will do it again. Questions. 1. Can I use same the same Github link which downloads "Microsoft.Spark.Worker.netcoreapp3.1.linux-x64-2.1.1.tar.gz" for .Net 6.0 or 8.0 application? 2. Should I publish the code as winx-64 or linux-x64 runtime based and self contained? My Operating System is Windows10.

You can use github link and in command you give github like this
set +e
/bin/bash $DBFS_INSTALLATION_ROOT/install-worker.sh github $DOTNET_SPARK_RELEASE $DOTNET_SPARK_WORKER_INSTALLATION_PATH in db init script.

Thanks JayashankarGS. i tried but i got the following error.                                                                                 run failed with error message Cluster '0909-195951-dphyuu7j' was terminated. Reason: INIT_SCRIPT_FAILURE (CLIENT_ERROR). Parameters: instance_id:c262a3b710c74a6f8627f0e6a750caa8, databricks_error_message:Cluster scoped init script /Shared/db-init.sh failed: Script exit status is non-zero.

i also use dbfs:/cluster-logs/ but i did not get any error.  I just mention some info. for example. /dbfs/spark-dotnet/install-worker.sh: line 66: hdfs: command not found.  ar (child): /tmp/temp_worker.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now                                                                           chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/spark-dotnet/Microsoft.Spark.Worker-2.1.1/Microsoft.Spark.Worker': No such file or directory
